# DelegateAuthenticationProvider not found after updating Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-msal

I have the following code (copied from Microsoft Learn), that was working fine with Microsoft.Graph 4.54.0

```
var authProvider = new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (request) => {
                // Use Microsoft.Identity.Client to retrieve token
                var assertion = new UserAssertion(token.AccessToken);
                var result = await clientApplication.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf(scopes, assertion).ExecuteAsync();

                request.Headers.Authorization =
                    new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
            });
```

I then created a new project using Microsoft.Graph 5.0.0 and Microsoft.Graph.Core 3.0.0, this gives an error that DelegateAuthenticationProvider could not be found.

How do I create an AuthenticationProvider that I can use with the GraphServiceClient?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I haven't figured your issue out because I never used your code before, I just followed [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#on-behalf-of-provider) to create `GraphServiceClient` via on-behalf-of flow. I will try to continue. Here's what I already got and it worked.

```
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Microsoft.Graph;

namespace WebMvcGraph5Ofo.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class HelloController : ControllerBase
    {
        public async Task<string> Get() {
            StringValues authorizationToken;
            HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out authorizationToken);
            var token = authorizationToken.ToString().Replace("Bearer ","");
            var scopes = new[] { "User.Read.All" };
            var tenantId = "tenantId";
            var clientId = "client_id";
            var clientSecret = "client_secret";
            var onBehalfOfCredential = new OnBehalfOfCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, token);
            var tokenRequestContext = new TokenRequestContext(scopes);
            var token2 = onBehalfOfCredential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext, new CancellationToken()).Result.Token;
            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(onBehalfOfCredential, scopes);
            var user = await graphClient.Users.GetAsync();
            return "hello";
        }

        [Route("ClientCredentialFlow")]
        public async Task<string> clientAsync() {
            var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
            var tenantId = "tenantId";
            var clientId = "client_id";
            var clientSecret = "client_secret";
            var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                            tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
            var users = await graphClient.Users.GetAsync();
            return "world";
        }
        
        [Route("provider")]
        public async Task<string> providerAsync()
        {
            StringValues authorizationToken;
            HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out authorizationToken);
            string incomingToken = authorizationToken.ToString().Replace("Bearer ", "");
            TokenProvider provider = new TokenProvider();
            provider.token = incomingToken;
            var authenticationProvider = new BaseBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider(provider);
            var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);
            var user = await graphServiceClient.Users.GetAsync();
            return "!!";
        }
    }
    
    public class TokenProvider : IAccessTokenProvider
    {
        public string token { get; set; }
        public AllowedHostsValidator AllowedHostsValidator => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public Task<string> GetAuthorizationTokenAsync(Uri uri, Dictionary<string, object>? additionalAuthenticationContext = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(token);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

=========================================================

Just like what @user2250152 shared,

> In place of the DelegateAuthenticationProvider, custom authentication
> flows can be done creating an implementation of IAccessTokenProvider,
> and using with the BaseBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider from the
> Kiota abstractions as follows

we can't use `DelegateAuthenticationProvider` any more to use it directly to `new GraphServiceClient(delegateAuthenticationProvider)`, if we want to generate the auth_provider to `new GraphServiceClient`, we have to follow to use `BaseBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider + IAccessTokenProvider`. I had a test like below, it can work but seems not meet the requirement for on-behalf-of flow.

Just like you know, the whole flow for O-B-O should be, using an access token A to call the web API which is protected by AAD, then the API code use O-B-O flow to generate a new access token B to do other request, such as calling graph API.

Then the scope or role for token A should look like `api://xxxx/scope_name(.default for role)`, and the scope for token B should be graph API scope such as `User.Read.All`.

In my test, I used graph client so that I don't need to generate token B, but it still need to authenticate the graph client. I found that when I pass token A with `api://xxxx/scope_name` to auth the graph client, I will get error, but when the token A is generated by graph API scope, I will successfully auth the graph client.

[image]

Comment: Bearer token get expire in 2 hours or even after setting policy token get expire after 24 hours so how to get new access token?

Comment: Using refresh token(when we use auth code flow so that we could have a refresh token along with access token) or get signing in again to generate a new access token. Access token expiration should be the expected behavior as it's used to visit security resources. Using client credential flow, then we could only generate a new access token.

Comment: i am using this to get token, but its not returning refresh_token `ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder builder = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(_msAuthConfig.ClientId).WithRedirectUri(_msAuthConfig.MsToAppRedirectUrl).WithTenantId(_msAuthConfig.TenantId).WithClientSecret(_msAuthConfig.ClientSecret);
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApp = builder.Build();
AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeParameterBuilder acquireTokenBuilder = confidentialClientApp.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(scopes, code);
AuthenticationResult rslt = await acquireTokenBuilder.ExecuteAsync();`

Comment: yeah, then pls call this method once again to obtain a new access token.

Comment: I can only redeem code once if i use same code again to get new access token then it throw exception like `Authorization code was already redeemed`. And once we asked user to sign in then we have keep this integration working and can not ask to login again after 2 hours. How this could be fixed, this will be very help full if we can do

Comment: I'm not very sure how you set in your app about it. Per my understanding, when we integrate related SDK(authentication mechanism) into the app, the authentication flow should be triggered automatically. I'm afraid you might create a question in this tag with more details about your issue.

Answer (score 8):

For Microsoft.Graph v5.0.0 the `GraphServiceClient` constructor accepts instances of `TokenCredential` from `Azure.Identity` package.

There is a lot of classes derived from [TokenCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.core.tokencredential?view=azure-dotnet#definition) like
`InteractiveBrowserCredential` or `ClientSecretCredential`

Example for `InteractiveBrowserCredential`

```
var interactiveBrowserCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(interactiveBrowserCredentialOptions);
var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(interactiveBrowserCredential);
```

Not sure but probably [OnBehalfOfCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.onbehalfofcredential?view=azure-dotnet) class is similar to Microsoft.Identity `UserAssertion`

Resource:

[Upgrade to v5: authentication](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/feature/5.0/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#authentication)

Answer (score 5):

Also had the same problem, I resolved it according to the documentation:
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/feature/5.0/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#authentication

This was my solution:

```
public class TokenProvider : IAccessTokenProvider
{
    public async Task<string> GetAuthorizationTokenAsync(Uri uri, Dictionary<string, object> additionalAuthenticationContext = default,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        //Tried to adjust this part to your code.
        // Use Microsoft.Identity.Client to retrieve token
        var assertion = new UserAssertion(token.AccessToken);
        var result = await clientApplication.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf(scopes, assertion).ExecuteAsync();

        return result.AccessToken;
    }

    public AllowedHostsValidator AllowedHostsValidator { get; }
}
```

And the use:

```
var authenticationProvider = new BaseBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider(new TokenProvider(configuration));
graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: there is no token property in IAccessTokenProvider

Comment: True, I matched that code to his question.
An actual code could like like this:
var scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
                IConfidentialClientApplication clientApp = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
        .Create(clientId)
        .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
        .WithAuthority($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/v2.0")
        .Build();

                var authResult = await clientApp.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
                return authResult.AccessToken;

Or any other implementation.

Answer (score 2):

The Interactive provider authentication provider works for a desktop application as I think DelegateAuthenticationProvider used to - it pops up a sign-in dialog.  There is sample code here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#interactive-provider.  All the other samples I found on the web use device token authentication, which is unfriendly.  The code below (adapted from the sample) works for me:

```
// User auth token credential
    private static InteractiveBrowserCredential? interactiveCredential;
    // Client configured with user authentication
    private static GraphServiceClient? _userClient;
    private static string[] scopes = new[] { "User.Read" };

     public static void InitializeGraphForUserAuth()
     {         

        var tenantId = "common";

        var clientId = "[Your client ID]";

        var options = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions
        {
            TenantId = tenantId,
            ClientId = clientId,
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,

            // RedirectUri must be http://localhost or http://localhost:PORT,
// and must be added to the RedirectUris in the Azure app registration

            RedirectUri = new Uri("http://localhost"),
        };


        interactiveCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(options);

        _userClient = new GraphServiceClient(interactiveCredential, scopes);
    }`
```

If you put this into the sample application at   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/dotnet?tabs=aad in place of the InitializeGraphForUserAuth function there (which uses device code authentication) and make conforming changes you can get a token and call the API.

Comment: this one only works on public client apps

Answer (score 1):

i had same problem for authenticating  Behalf of a user. 
you can use an Authentication Provider class

```cs
using Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions;
using Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions.Authentication;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace GraphHelper;

public class TokenProvider : IAuthenticationProvider
{
    private async Task<string> GenerateToken()
    {
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var tokenUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/[YOUR_TENANT_ID]/oauth2/token";
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, tokenUrl);

            request.Headers.Add("Referer", "login.microsoftonline.com");
            request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.Headers.Add("CacheControl", "no-cache");

            var AuthenticationContext = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                { "grant_type", "password" },
                    { "client_id", "[YOUR_CLIENT_ID]" },
                    { "client_secret", "[YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET]" },
                    { "resource", "[YOUR_RESOURCE]" },
                    { "username", "[YOUR_USERNAME]" },
                    { "password", "[YOUR_PASSWORD]" }
                };

            request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(AuthenticationContext);

            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var oAuthResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OAuthResponse>(content);
                return oAuthResponse.access_token;
            }

            throw new Exception("Authentication problem" + response.ReasonPhrase);

        }
    }

    public async Task AuthenticateRequestAsync(RequestInformation request, Dictionary<string, object>? additionalAuthenticationContext = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var token = await GenerateToken();
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"bearer {token}");
    }

    
}
```

Just create an instance of this class and pass it as paramter to GraphServiceClient constructor

```cs
   var tokenProvider = new TokenProvider();
            return new GraphServiceClient(tokenProvider);
```

by each request to Graph , AuthenticateRequestAsync will be executed and a new token will be generated.
you can manage Generating token when it really needed ( when you don't have a token or when it has been expired)